# Splitting text into sentences using regex in Python

Tags: python, regex, split

I'm trying to split a piece sample text into a list of sentences without delimiters and no spaces at the end of each sentence.

Sample text:

The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring. Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2. It will change your view of the matrix. Are the human people the ones who started the war? Is AI a bad thing?

Into this (desired output):

```
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2', 'It will change your view of the matrix', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war', 'Is AI a bad thing']
```

My code is currently:

```
def sent_tokenize(text):
    sentences = re.split(r"[.!?]", text)
    sentences = [sent.strip(" ") for sent in sentences]
    return sentences
```

However this outputs (current output):

```
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2', 'It will change your view of the matrix', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war', 'Is AI a bad thing', '']
```

Notice the extra '' on the end.

Any ideas on how to remove the extra '' at the end of my current output?

Comment: Any reason for _not_ using `nltk.sent_tokenize`?

Comment: You might have an extra space at the end. Just check. You can start by running `.strip()` to take care of this.

Comment: @DyZ Great minds (see my answer) :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I know :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any ideas on how to remove the extra '' at the end of my current
>   output?

You could remove it by doing this:

```
sentences[:-1]
```

Or faster (by ᴄᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ)

```
del result[-1]
```

Output:

```
['The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring', 'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2', 'It will change your view of the matrix', 'Are the human people the ones who started the war', 'Is AI a bad thing']
```

Answer (score 12):

#### `nltk`'s `sent_tokenize`

If you're in the business of NLP, I'd strongly recommend [`sent_tokenize`](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#nltk.tokenize.sent_tokenize) from the `nltk` package.

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import sent_tokenize
>>> sent_tokenize(text)
[
    'The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring.',
    'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2.',
    'It will change your view of the matrix.',
    'Are the human people the ones who started the war?',
    'Is AI a bad thing?'
]
```

It's a lot more robust than regex, and provides a lot of options to get the job done. More info can be found at the [official documentation](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html).

If you are picky about the trailing delimiters, you can use `nltk.tokenize.RegexpTokenizer` with a slightly different pattern:

```
>>> from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
>>> tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[^.?!]+')
>>> list(map(str.strip, tokenizer.tokenize(text)))    
[
    'The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring',
    'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2',
    'It will change your view of the matrix',
    'Are the human people the ones who started the war',
    'Is AI a bad thing'
]
```

---

#### Regex-based `re.split`

If you *must* use `regex`, then you'll need to modify your pattern by adding a negative lookahead -

```
>>> list(map(str.strip, re.split(r"[.!?](?!$)", text)))
[
    'The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring',
    'Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2',
    'It will change your view of the matrix',
    'Are the human people the ones who started the war',
    'Is AI a bad thing?'
]
```

The added `(?!$)` specifies that you split only when you do not have not reached the end of the line yet. Unfortunately, I am not sure the trailing delimiter on the last sentence can be reasonably removed without doing something like `result[-1] = result[-1][:-1]`.

Comment: "without delimiters". Look at the desired output.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 imo, that is a minor detail. I'll see what I can do though.

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 I've added an option with RegexpTokenizer which addresses this concern. Hope it's alright now!

Comment: I have to use regex, didn't have access to nltk package. The regex answer worked but left '?' at the end of the final sentence.

Comment: @DanielBourke A shame, really. But I can respect that. Good luck!

Comment: @DanielBourke, try this: `listy[-1]=listy[-1][:-1]` to remove the ?

Comment: @ᴡʜᴀᴄᴋᴀᴍᴀᴅᴏᴏᴅʟᴇ3000 While that would solve the problem, it would also mean that two operations are still required to get OP's output. In that case, one may as well stick to what OP is currently doing, and then use your answer. Maybe improve upon it with `del result[-1]` (basically a more efficient version of your answer) to do the same thing. By the way, if you want to add `del result[-1]` in your answer, feel free to.

Comment: Sure, thanks for the tip.

Comment: `(?<!$)` is a lookbehind (see Option 2 description). You might want to use a lookahead, but `(?<!$)` = `(?!$)` since `$` is a zero-width assertion.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks for the input, appreciated. That was an oversight on my part.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **filter** to remove the empty elements

**Ex:**

```
import re
text = """The first time you see The Second Renaissance it may look boring. Look at it at least twice and definitely watch part 2. It will change your view of the matrix. Are the human people the ones who started the war? Is AI a bad thing?"""
def sent_tokenize(text):
    sentences = re.split(r"[.!?]", text)
    sentences = [sent.strip(" ") for sent in sentences]
    return filter(None, sentences)

print sent_tokenize(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could either `strip` your paragraph first before splitting it or filter empty strings in the result out.